# How does laravel cast works under the hood

Tags: laravel, eloquent

laravel $cast property in model which mutate the data type of a data returned from database.

how does it work behind the scene ?
can it be use for a json column in which has possibility of returning large data from database.

Example
let's say for instance my database query was suppose to return 200 result how does laravel mutate the data type for a particular set of items in those 200 database query result

Comment: Behind the seen [blob](https://docs.w3cub.com/laravel~8/api/8.x/illuminate/contracts/database/eloquent/castsattributes#method_get) . You get all the detailed reference there

Comment: Scenario: when the column is defined to be a `json` column and we must encode the data   using `json_encode()` manually and should deode when accessing the data. But upon declaring a casted column setting the column as `array` which supports `json`. We wouldn't have to encode the data manually. It encodes in the fly and decode in the fly. Very convienient. I am not sure how it supports large data.

Comment: If its large  data was how I became curious

Comment: Check this answer on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravels-json-table-migration-data-type-length)

Comment: I edit the question please take a look at it